# What is the actual use of a shared module in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I read on several Best Practices sides the same project structure for angular web applications. Examples are [aglowildsolutions](https://aglowiditsolutions.com/blog/angular-best-practices/), [tatvasoft](https://www.tatvasoft.com/blog/angular-optimization-and-best-practices/) or even the [angular homepage](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module). But I don't get the use of a shared module.

For instance, I use angular material design. That means I have about 10 material components. I have 5 feature modules and in each feature module I use 2 different material components.
But to use them in these feature modules, I have to import the entire shared module into each  feature module. Which means I still import everything the shared module offers. Isn't that practically the same as having everything just in the app module? Or the core module?

I dont see any advantage here. Its even the opposite. It makes the project structure much more crowded and inflates the amount of code which might even slow down the performance.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the shared module is an old practice for lazy programmers.
This doesn't enable tree-shaking and leads to big bundle size.

My advice is to create on module for every single component. Import only the needed Material modules in each Component-Module.

Doing this your code will be more organized, enables good lazy loading and  tree-shaking and also refactoring will be simpler

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I am currently looking for experienced Angular developers who can give me some advice because all the online articles about Angular might be nothing but hot air. Do you know something on this? Or is there a template project which is known for being state-of-the-art?

Comment: hmmm no... there is a discord server called "Angular Community" where you can ask questions if you like